# Delete from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that initially has the following details in it

```
+-------+--------------+------------+-------+
| T_KEY |    T_DATE    | T_TEN      | T_MEM |
+-------+--------------+------------+-------+
|    1  |  0000-00-00  | a          |    0  |
|    2  |  0000-00-00  | b          |    0  |
|    3  |  0000-00-00  | c          |    0  |
|    4  |  0000-00-00  | d          |    0  |
|    5  |  0000-00-00  | e          |    0  |
|    6  |  0000-00-00  | f          |    0  |
+-------+--------------+------------+-------+
```

After insert, the table looks as below

```
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------+
| T_KEY |    T_DATE    | T_TEN     |  T_MEM |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------+
|    1  | 0000-00-00   | a         |     0  |
|    2  | 0000-00-00   | b         |     0  |
|    3  | 0000-00-00   | c         |     0  |
|    4  | 0000-00-00   | d         |     0  |
|    5  | 0000-00-00   | e         |     0  |
|    6  | 0000-00-00   | f         |     0  |
|    7  | 2015-01-01   | a         |     1  |
|    8  | 2015-01-01   | b         |     3  |
|    9  | 2015-01-01   | c         |     5  |
|    10 | 2015-01-02   | a         |     5  |
|    11 | 2015-01-02   | b         |     8  |
|    12 | 2015-01-02   | c         |     1  |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

During the insert operation, for T_TEN=a,b,c non-zero values have been inserted for T_DATE & T_MEM fields. After the insert operation, I'd like to run a cleanup operation(delete query) which should identify all the T_TEN that have a row of data each for
T_DATE='0000-00-00' and T_MEM = 0
AND
T_DATE="Any value other than '0000-00-00'"
AND
T_MEM = "Any value other than zero"

Once, identified, it should delete the row that contains T_DATE='0000-00-00' and T_MEM = 0 for that particular T_TEN.

In the above example, after the insert for say T_TEN=a, the updated table has 3 entries for 'a' which are

```
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------+
| T_KEY |    T_DATE    | T_TEN     |  T_MEM |
+-------+--------------+-----------+--------+
|    1  |  0000-00-00  | a         |     0  |
|    7  |  2015-01-02  | a         |     1  |
|    10 |  2015-01-02  | a         |     5  |
```

I'd like to get rid of the row with T_KEY=1 as T_TEN=a, now has both zero & non-zero values for the fields T_DATE & T_MEM.

Similarly, for T_TEN=b & c, I'd like to remove the rows with T_DATE='0000-00-00' and T_MEM = 0 as they have got a non-zero entry for these fields following the insert.

### REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| T_KEY |    T_DATE   |  T_TEN      | T_MEM |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|    4  | 0000-00-00  | d           |    0  |
|    5  | 0000-00-00  | e           |    0  |
|    6  | 0000-00-00  | f           |    0  |
|    7  | 2015-01-01  | a           |    1  |
|    8  | 2015-01-01  | b           |    3  |
|    9  | 2015-01-01  | c           |    5  |
|   10  | 2015-01-02  | a           |    5  |
|   11  | 2015-01-02  | b           |    8  |
|   12  | 2015-01-02  | c           |    1  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

### INSERT SQL I AM USING IS

```
INSERT INTO 
        databse_2.th_sc(T_DATE,T_TEN,T_MEM)     
            SELECT  
                        ms1.M_DATE,
                        ms1.M_TEN, 
                        CASE
                            WHEN SUM(ms1.MEM_US) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1
                            WHEN SUM(ms1.MEM_US) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 3
                            WHEN SUM(ms1.MEM_US) BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 5
                            WHEN SUM(ms1.MEM_US) BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 8
                            WHEN SUM(ms1.MEM_US) BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN 10
                            WHEN SUM(ms1.MEM_US) > 50 THEN 15
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS MEM_TI
            FROM
                        database_1.MEM_SW ms1
            WHERE 
                        ms1.MEM_IN IN ( 
                             SELECT 
                                    tw2.T_NAME
                             FROM 
                                     database_1.T_WY tw2
                        ) 
                        AND ms1.M_DATE between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-01' 
                        AND ms1.MEM_IN LIKE 'ks%ny%'  
            GROUP BY 
                        ms1.M_DATE,
                        ms1.MEM_TEN;
```

Could someone help me on how to achieve this please?

Comment: One way to do this is to work with the INSERT statement. Can you share it?

Comment: Hello Ahmad - I've updated the question with the insert SQL

Comment: Oh, after posting my answer, I just notice: Is it possible for a record to have T_DATE = '0000-00-00' and T_MEM <> 0 or vice versa?

Comment: Hello Thorsten - Thank you very much. I'll test this now. Just T_DATE is good enough for test. if T_DATE is zero, then surely T_MEM =0. However, with T_DATE non-zero, T_MEM can be zero or a non-zero number.

Comment: Hello Thorsten - Sorry for the wrong update earlier. I get the below error when I run the SQL - MySQL said: Documentation

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Thank you very very much Thorsten. I've amended you query to get it working. Will post the solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to getting over the error "Sorry for the wrong update earlier. I get the below error when I run the SQL - MySQL said: Documentation #1093 - You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause – "

is to wrap the inner SELECT with a SELECT.
(http://dasunhegoda.com/1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-table_name-for-update-in-from-clause/104/)

```
 DELETE 
    FROM  
            mytable
    WHERE 
            t_date = '0000-00-00'
            AND t_ten IN (
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT
                            t_ten
                    FROM 
                            mytable
                    WHERE 
                            NOT (t_date = '0000-00-00')
                ) AS  XY
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete from the table where t_date and t_mem are empty but a record exists with the same t_ten where t_date and t_mem are not both empty. Use EXISTS or IN for this:

```
delete 
from mytable
where t_date = '0000-00-00' and t_mem = 0
and t_ten in
(
  select t_ten
  from mytable
  where not (t_date = '0000-00-00' and t_mem = 0)
);
```